# Can someone share an OpenSSL sample code?

Tags: openssl

I have been searching and trying various suggestions but none seem to work properly.

In order to demonstrate the correct way of programming SSL_read(), SSL_write(), SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ and SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE, will there be any sample code to share? Thanks a lot.

Comment: https://github.com/TalkWithTLS/TalkWithTLS/blob/master/src/sample/openssl_nb_client.c  : This sample code has explained how to handle WANT_READ and WANT_WRITE in OpenSSL APIs (SSL_connect, SSL_read and SSL_write)

Answer (score 2):

Following are the steps to use SSL (for client)

1. Create socket and establish a TCP connection.
2. Create a SSL_CTX structure and BIO * (bind the socket)
3. Create a SSL structure using SSL_CTX
4. Call SSL_connect
5. If step 3 is successful, continue, else return error
6. Call SSL_write and SSL_read after that.
7. Close the connection
8. Cleanup the allocated structures.

For server, you need to use SSL_accept.

```
//Step 1
SSL_CTX * sslctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv3_client_method);
BIO * sock = BIO_new_socket((int)your_tcp_socket, BIO_NOCLOSE);
//Step 2
SSL * ssl = SSL_new(sslctx);
//Step 3
SSL_connect(ssl);

//for server
SSL_accept(ssl);
```